# How can I limit a Custom Shape to safe area in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have 2 Shapes **CustomShape1** is limited to safeArea and it is okay, but **CustomShape2** is ignores safeArea out of the box, which I am not okay with it. In **CustomShape1** I could pass the origin and size to limit my Shape available Space to SafeArea, but I do not have or I do not see a way to pass origin or size for **CustomShape2** which is just a Circle, so how can I solve this issue, that **CustomShape2** respect safeArea as well right of the box?

I found out adding padding modifier would solve the issue not in the way I wanted, I do not want use view modifier to solve shape issue. As you can see adding `.padding(.vertical, 0.1)` would limit the view to safeArea, I do know should I call this a bug or what!

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {

        ZStack {
            
            CustomShape1()
                .fill(Color.red)
            
            CustomShape2()
                .fill(Color.blue)
                .background(Color.black.opacity(0.8))
                //.padding(.vertical, 0.1) // Adding This Would solve the issue!
            
        }

    }
}


struct CustomShape1: Shape {
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        Path { path in
            path.addRect(CGRect(origin: rect.origin, size: rect.size))
        }
    }
}


struct CustomShape2: Shape {
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        Path { path in
            path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.midY), radius: 50, startAngle: Angle(degrees: 0), endAngle: Angle(degrees: 360), clockwise: true)
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: It is not a shape, the shape is ok with safe area. It is background. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/70634989/12299030 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/70707500/12299030 for same issue and solution.

Comment: @Asperi: Thanks, but those links has nothing to do with my issue, I believe background is just use available Space from Shape. Background has no power to extend itself over safeArea, unless the Available Space was already ignores safeArea. I believe this is maybe an issue from Shape.

Answer (score 1):

Set `.clipped()`.

```
.background(Color.blue.opacity(0.8).clipped()) // <===Here
```

Comment: It is worth to remembering that I am not looking for view modifier. I asked How can I solve the issue right of the box.